# Ubuntu 16.04 screenshot leaves artifact on monitor

Tags: 16.04, screenshot

Whenever I take a sized screenshot on ubuntu (i.e. using SHIFT + PRINT), it leaves a shaded area on my monitor, matching exactly to the size of the screenshot. Each screenshot will leave another shaded area. If they overlap, then the shaded area gets darker and darker.

The only way that I've found to remove it is to log off or restart.

Any ideas on what's causing this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you take a screenshot. U need to close the application. If you minimise it or leave it in the background it leaves the shaded box. I experienced the same thing.

[image]

Once you have taken the screenshot you get this application either copy to clipboard or save the screenshot and then close the application. Once you close the application the shaded area will disappear. The shaded area marks where you have taken the screenshot. If you have several of this application open than you will have several shaded areas so save the images and close them all and the shaded areas will disappear.